# How to upgrade or downgrade a kernel in Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: kernel

Ubuntu 17.04 is using the 4.10 kernel which introduces [massive system instability](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99295#c22). How can I downgrade to the 4.9 kernel or the 4.11.6+ kernel, either of which are unaffected by the issue?

Comment: You can install any mainline kernel you like from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Comment: How would I add it as a software source?

Comment: You can't add it as a software source. You can download and install deb files.

Comment: Your link is to a bug that appeared 4 months ago and was likely fixed a week or two later. Although I didn't check that out.

Comment: I wouldn't be posing this question if I didn't have the issue 4 months later on a daily basis.